# Python : Flask view function did not return a response

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am trying to run a web service that takes ressource and account as arguments and returns the user pasword, but it returns me some errors :

```
raise ValueError('View function did not return a response')
ValueError: View function did not return a response
```

here is the stucture of my code :

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

# Config
TOKEN = "" 
SERVER = "" 

# Classes
class PClient():
    def __init__(self, token=TOKEN, server=SERVER):
        self.token = token
        self.server = server 
        self.cache = {} 
        pass

    def getPassword(self, resource, account):
        if resource in self.cache and account in self.cache[resource]:
            return self.cache[resource][account]
        else :
            return "Something"

# Script
app = Flask(__name__) 
pmp = PClient() 

@app.route('/<string:resource>/<string:account>')
def get_password(resource, account):
    global pmp
    return pmp.getPassword(resource, account)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=2999, debug=True)
```

Any Idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Flask source](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/0.11/flask/app.py#L1731), your view function returns `None`. You need to check your code that inserts values into `self.cache[resource][account]`.